# Tinymce mceToggleEditor scroll/focus issue

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I have 50+ textareas that I am using tinyMCE with. Instead of loading each one I am just initialising them, then activing them later on request

**Initialisation**

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "none",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : false,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    auto_focus : false
});
```

**Edit Observer**

```
$('ul span.edit-details').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    id = id.replace('edit-','');
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceToggleEditor',false,'editor-'+id);
});
```

**UPDATE  I have also tried**

```
$('ul span.edit-details').click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    id = id.replace('edit-','');
    if($('#details-'+id).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#details-'+id).show();
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'editor-'+id);
    }
    else {
        $('#details-'+id).hide();
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'editor-'+id);
    }
});
```

The problem I  have is that when `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceToggleEditor',false,'editor-'+id);` fires the pages focuses/scrolls to that textarea, even if it is already in the viewport.

Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using mcetoggleEditor for performance reasons over mceAddControl/mceRemoveControl?

Comment: Nope... I will switch and see if I  get any difference

Comment: So, your problem is which one in detail (can you describe exactly what you do and what happens; i wasn't able to recreate the problem on my machine)  ?

Comment: I have just worked it out!!! It only happens when I have a # at the end of the URL!?!?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After all this testing on difference browsers etc...

The issue was that I had an anchor `#` at the end of my URL loading the page with out this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Damn it was very annoying for me to find out the issue, it was the anchor a href="#"

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

solved it